# Why do we assign size (like char(20) or varchar(20) in string data type and not for data types like int or float in SQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Why do we assign size (like char(20) or varchar(20) in string data type and not for data types like int or float in SQL)?

Comment: In some RDBMS some other datatypes do have a size option.  In Oracle they don't, you just have different data-types.  It's as simple as that.  For example, Instead of INT(4), INT(8), etc you'd just use INT and BIGINT.  And then there's FLOAT and DOUBLE, etc, etc.  Mostly because INT(5) doesn't have much point being supported over INT(8), etc.  So, instead of INT(n) you just get INT(4) and INT(8), etc, but they get renamed to INT and BIGINT.  Much like in other programming languages.

Comment: because strings are commonly variable length and other data types are not.

Comment: @Dems: In MySQL at least, [integer attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) are display-width, not storage size.

Answer (score 2):

Numeric types are so called "fixed-size" types. The storage size for that column does not change regardless of which value you store in. By choosing the type, you define the size of it. An `integer` uses less space than a `bigint`.

You also (implicitely) define a constraint on the column that restricts the the maximum and minium values that can be stored (a `bigint` can hold bigger numbers than an `integer`).

The length specification for character types serves a similar purpose: it defines a constraint on what the maximum length of the data should be.

For `char` columns this also defines the storage size, as `char` is a fixed-length datatype as well (shorter values are padded to the defined length)

For all(?) modern DBMS the defined (max) size of a varying character (`varchar`) column doesn't really change the way it's stored. The DBMS just ensures that you cannot store more than what you specified (similar to the fact that you cannot store a number that exceeds the defined range for an integer column).

The DBMS *might* apply some internal (non-documented) optimization depending on the defined maximum size, but that's not "visible" to the systems accessing the data.

Comment: The max size of a `[n]char` column certainly changes the way it is stored in SQL Server except if using compression. Did you intend that to apply only to `[n]varchar`?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, if I remember correctly, int and float are some kind of shortcuts for number(x,y) definition.